# Kendo with Backbone Routing

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, kendo-ui, url-routing

I know that Kendo is capable to integrate itself to use datasource from Backbone. I like it's UI, but, how can I use Kendo UI (especially Kendo Mobile) without it's router and use Backbone Router as it's alternative? It would be great if Kendo can use Backbone router as it's default. Sorry for my bad english. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Kendo UI Mobile - you can't.

Kendo UI Mobile is a very tight framework, with all of the individual parts bound together. This is done for performance reasons on mobile devices. If you want to use Kendo UI Mobile, then you should stick with Kendo UI Mobile for routing, view management, etc.

Now, Kendo UI Web ... that's a different story. You can easily use Backbone to your heart's content with the Web framework. The [KendoUI-Backbone](https://github.com/kendo-labs/kendo-backbone) project that you're already familiar with, aims to make this as easy as possible (though it still needs work to get there).